# Adding a "not related" flag for comments

Tags: feature-request, flags, comments

Would it be possible to have a "not related to question" flag added as I have come across a few times when this would have been amazing to have?

Comment: "Not constructive" or "too chatty" work for this. If they're not related to the question, then they're definitely not constructive, and most likely too chatty.

Answer (score 9):

That sounds like a perfect fit for the existing **Not Constructive** reason.  Because of this, I don't think we need this new comment flag reason.